# Modifying multiple UIButtons efficiently

Tags: swift, uibutton

There are 3 buttons on in my view which I'm trying to add a shadow to. Here is my code:

```
@IBOutlet weak var button1: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var button2: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var button3: UIButton!


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    button1.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
    button1.layer.shadowOpacity = 1
    button1.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 5, height: 5)
    button1.layer.shadowRadius = 0
    button2.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
    button2.layer.shadowOpacity = 1
    button2.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 5, height: 5)
    button2.layer.shadowRadius = 0
    button3.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
    button3.layer.shadowOpacity = 1
    button3.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 5, height: 5)
    button3.layer.shadowRadius = 0 
}
```

Is there a more efficient way to do  this sort of thing to multiple buttons instead of just repeating the same code for each one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add your buttons to an outlet collection in Interface Builder

```
@IBOutlet var buttonsWithShadow: [UIButton]!
```

Now you can iterate over the collection, and configure all buttons in the same way:

```
for button in buttonsWithShadow {
    button.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
    button.layer.shadowOpacity = 1
    button.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 5, height: 5)
    button.layer.shadowRadius = 0
}
```